# GCC converts private inherited to parent

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc

I was trying to wrap boost intrusive ptr with my own ptr which overloads the casting to bool. In addition, in my ptr I would like to restrict access to some of the boost intrusive ptrmethods. At first I used boost intrusive ptr as a private member of my ptr and used the bool idiom, and it worked well and used the bool idiom. 
At some point from my own special reasons I needed the new ptr to be type of boost intrusive ptr, so I used private inheritance, but that didn't work. From some reason gcc tries to handle my ptr as a boost intrusive ptr and refuses to use the publicly exposed bool idiom.
Here is a sample code which demonstrates it:

```
#include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>
#include <stdio.h>

class Object
{
    public:
        Object() : _refCount(0) {}
        void addRef() { _refCount++; }
        unsigned int releaseRef() { return --_refCount; }

    private:
        unsigned int  _refCount;
};

inline void intrusive_ptr_release(Object* p)
{
    if (p->releaseRef() == 0)
    {
        delete p;
    }
}

inline void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(Object* p)
{
    p->addRef();
}

// Option A: using private member
template<class ObjectT>
class PtrA
{
    public:
        explicit PtrA(ObjectT* obj) : _obj(obj) {}
        PtrA() {}

        ObjectT* operator->() { return _obj.operator->(); }
        const ObjectT* operator->() const { return _obj.operator->(); }

        ObjectT* get() { return _obj.get(); }
        const ObjectT* get() const { return _obj.get(); }

        typedef const ObjectT* (PtrA::*unspecified_bool_type)() const;

        operator unspecified_bool_type() const
        {
            if (_obj != NULL)
            {
                printf("ptr is not null\n");
            }

            return _obj.get() == 0 ? 0: (unspecified_bool_type)&PtrA::get;
        }

    private:
        boost::intrusive_ptr<ObjectT> _obj;
};

// Option B: using private inheritance
template<class ObjectT>
class PtrB : private boost::intrusive_ptr<ObjectT>
{
    public:
        explicit PtrB(ObjectT* obj) : boost::intrusive_ptr<ObjectT>(obj) {}
        PtrB() {}

        using boost::intrusive_ptr<ObjectT>::operator->;
        using boost::intrusive_ptr<ObjectT>::get;

        typedef const ObjectT* (PtrB::*unspecified_bool_type)() const;

        operator unspecified_bool_type() const
        {
            const ObjectT* p = boost::intrusive_ptr<ObjectT>::get();
            if (p != NULL)
            {
                printf("ptr is not null\n");
            }

            return p == 0 ? 0 : (unspecified_bool_type)&PtrB::get;
        }
};

int main()
{
    // this verison compiles
    // PtrA<Object> obj(new Object());

    PtrB<Object> obj(new Object());

    if (obj == NULL)
    {
        printf("object is null\n");
    }
    if (!obj)
    {
        printf("object is null\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Using PtrB in this code results in a compilation error:

```
g++ -std=c++11 ./test.cpp
...
./test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
./test.cpp:88:16: error: 'boost::intrusive_ptr<Object>' is an inaccessible base of 'PtrB<Object>'
     if (obj == NULL)
                ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.hpp:167:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp:16,
                 from ./test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/detail/operator_bool.hpp:60:10: error: 'bool boost::intrusive_ptr<T>::operator!() const [with T = Object]' is inaccessible
     bool operator! () const BOOST_NOEXCEPT
          ^
./test.cpp:92:10: error: within this context
     if (!obj)
          ^
./test.cpp:92:10: error: 'boost::intrusive_ptr<Object>' is not an accessible base of 'PtrB<Object>'
```

If boost intrusive ptr is privately inherited, what does GCC tries to use it instead the public bool idiom?
I use gcc 4.8.5

Comment: @WhiZTiM I fixed the example for OP - you just have to change which line is commented.

Comment: @Barry, Ohhh... blind me... Yea.. Reproduced. Your answer explains it. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If boost intrusive ptr is privately inherited, what does GCC tries to use it instead the public bool idiom?

Private inhertiance doesn't change the rules of name lookup. It just makes the resulting best viable candidate ill-formed if it requires an inaccessible conversion. In this case, you're doing these operations:

```
if (obj == NULL)
if (!obj)
```

neither of those operations goes through your `operator unspecified_bool_type()`. The former finds:

```
template<class T, class U>
bool operator==(intrusive_ptr<T> const & a, U * b);
```

And the latter finds `intrusive_ptr<T>::operator!()`. Those are the best viable candidates for those two operations. Your operator would be a user-defined conversion sequence but the ones that `intrusive_ptr` provides are standasrd conversion sequences. But these two require a conversion from `PtrB<T>` to `intrusive_ptr<T>`, which is what makes them ill-formed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you have an idea how to overcome this issue? I tried to re-implement operator! and operator bool. But I still have a problem with operator== (which isn't supposed to be called in this case).

Comment: @michael Why isn't it supposed to be called? You're writing `==`. But if you don't want the `intrusive_ptr` ones to be called, you'll just have to write your own.

Comment: You are right, I didn't see intrusive ptr has an operator== which receives a nullptr_t. Thanks!